# How to properly capitalize a sentence?

Tags: python, string

This code below makes it capitalize the first letter in each sentence of the string, although it won't capitalize the letter "i":

```py
>>> a = "This is text i wrote. I want i to be capitalized."
>>> '. '.join(i.capitalize() for i in a.split('. '))
'This is text i wrote. I want i to be capitalized.'
```

How to properly capitalize all sentences in a string, i.e. the first letter of each sentence and all standalone "i"s?

Comment: Your code  seems to be correct , it's working . Can you please clarify the problem?

Comment: If I were to guess, OP wants any occurrences of the word `'i'` also to be capitalized, even if not at the start of a sentence.

Comment: I tried it and I have no problem, letter `i` is capitalized

Comment: you can add another line - `a = a.replace('i ', 'I').replace(' i.', 'I')` to deal with all rogue i's - before another word or at the end of a sentence.

Comment: `capitalize()` only capitalizes the first letter in a string; if you want to uppercase an `i` in the *middle* of a string, you will have to break the sentence into individual words, capitalize `"i"` when found in the resulting list, and join the words back into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you wish to capitalize the starts of sentences and the standalone word `I`. This can be done relatively easy using regular expressions:

```
def capitalize_text(s):
    s = re.sub(r'(?:(?<=\.)|^)(\s*)(.)', # Starts of sentences.
               lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).upper(), s)
    s = re.sub(r'\bi\b', 'I', s) # Single word 'i'.
    return s
```

Example:

```
>>> capitalize_text("this is a test i wrote. i think 'i' should be capitalized.")
"This is a test I wrote. I think 'I' should be capitalized."
```

Comment: @advikpro If my answer helped you, consider upvoting & accepting my answer.